# 'ref' declaration in pure react

Tags: html, reactjs, ref

I was taking the redux course on egghead.io by Dan abramov,he create a input field and assigned a ref attribute which seems like a functional assignment.The code follows as ,

```
<input ref={node => {input = node;}} />
    
<button onClick={() => { input.value = ''}> ADD</button>
```

Can you please explain this,Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature called [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs). If you pass a function to `ref`, it will be called with the DOM element as argument and you can do whatever you want with it. In your example that element is assigned to the `input` variable.

There are cases where you have to "escape" the React model and need access to the underlying DOM elements (e.g. for controlling focus), and refs are a (the?) way to do that.

Comment: You seemed correct bro,Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
const inputRef = React.useRef(null); // create ref of input using Hooks

<input ref={inputRef} /> // render input field and assign ref to it
    
// render button and when click on it, it reassign the input value to empty     
<button onClick={() => { inputRef.current.value = '' } > ADD </button>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to address the OP's question though.

Comment: ya @FelixKling, its ok no problem , i learnt from this prop though, good answer

Answer (score 1):

We use "**ref**" when we want to access the dom element object. and it's the react way to get the dom object.

You can use the traditional way to get the dom object **document.getElementById("inputId")** but the issue is you need to use it into the correct life cycle or else you might not get the element.

Another advantage of the ref is if the component is destroyed your ref object will also be destroyed.

Example:

```
<input id="inputId" ref={node => {input = node;}} />
    
<button onClick={() => { input.value = ''}> ADD</button>

console.log(input)

console.log(document.getElementById("inputId"))
```

Both the console will point to the same dom element

check this for more details https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html